# Codeigniter zip all files and download

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, zip

I have problem how I can download files from my server. I send my files to spec directory and saving infos about these files into my database. Inside my model i create function to get infos about single uploaded file:

```
public function getAllFiles($unique_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM download_files WHERE unique_id = '$unique_id'");
    return $query->result();
}
```

now, Inside my View I can display name etc. about file- but I dont have any idea how I can download ALL files in single file (ZIP).

My Loop inside View is:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($getAllFiles as $row): ?>
    <li><?php echo $row->file_name; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I know to do this I must use ZIP Library but I can't use it :( Anyone can help me ?

THANKS!

Comment: "I know to do this I must use ZIP Library but I can't use it" Why not? Please [edit] to explain your constraints better.

Comment: Becouse I dont have idea where I must put to archive my files :( Inside Model? Controller?

Comment: @eStasicki check this link https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/zip.html

Comment: @eStasicki here is the current codeigniter zip library http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/zip.html